# Apply a function to each element of a tuple ("map" a tuple)

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14, variadic

C++ doesn't (yet) have a ['map' higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)), certainly not one which applies to a compile-time sequence of values like a tuple. We have `std::transform`, and there's [an equivalent of it for tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820104/equivalent-of-stdtransform-for-tuples) listed on SO, but that's iterator-based, and anyway - I don't want to use any reference to the output. I want to pass a tuple and a function / variadic lambda, and get another tuple of the same length with the function applied to each element.

I'm also sure this has been implemented multiple times, but since I want to build up some "tuple confidence", I've done it myself. Here's what I got:

```
namespace detail {

template <class F, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
auto transform_each_impl(Tuple t, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(
        f(std::get<Is>(t) )...
    );
}

} // namespace detail

template <class F, typename... Args>
auto transform_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, F f) {
    return detail::transform_each_impl(
        t, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

And this works in the cases I've tried - I haven't tested extensively.

I'd like general feedback/suggestions, but also:

- When is the function resolved or instantiated in the case of different-type arguments? In what cases will it be the same (instantiated) function with forced conversion, as opposed to different instantiations for the different types? Am I really getting the latter at all?
- Is there any `std::forward`'ing that I need to do?
- Can I avoid a helper function somehow?
- What do you think about the name?

Comment: Not enough time for full review, but you seem to be copying the tuple in the helper function unnecessarily. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79c5c9073b96ed76).

Answer (score 6):

### transform, or map ?

I wouldn't name this function `transform`, because it's very different from that stl algorithm. `std::transform` can be used to modify a range in place, and can be called with either unary or binary operations. What you implement is generally called `map` and has its roots in functional languages; so I would call it `tuple_map`, for instance. Then the convention is to put the function first in the argument list, and the sequence second.

Or, you could try to implement `transform`, but then it gets tricky, because there are three "semantic inputs" to be considered: the tuple, its elements and the function signature. I haven't had the time to consider it thoroughly, but I believe that using `decltype(fn(std::get<0>(tuple)))` as a semantic clue is a good approximation. If it's `void`, you know that the semantic is at the tuple level; if it's an lvalue reference, you use `std::tie` to return a tuple of references; if it's an rvalue reference, `std::forward_as_tuple` is the most adapted; and if it's a value, you can return a new tuple.

### A sketch for `transform`

For instance, with C++ 17 enabled:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Fn, typename Argument, std::size_t... Ns>
auto tuple_transform_impl(Fn&& fn, Argument&& argument, std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ns) == 0) return std::tuple<>(); // empty tuple
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(fn(std::get<0>(argument))), void>) {
        (fn(std::get<Ns>(argument)),...); // no return value expected
        return;
    }
    // then dispatch lvalue, rvalue ref, temporary
    else if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(fn(std::get<0>(argument)))>) {
        return std::tie(fn(std::get<Ns>(argument))...);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(fn(std::get<0>(argument)))>) {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(fn(std::get<Ns>(argument))...);
    }
    else {
        return std::tuple(fn(std::get<Ns>(argument))...);
    }
}

template <typename Fn, typename... Ts>
auto tuple_transform(Fn&& fn, const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple) {
    return tuple_transform_impl(std::forward<Fn>(fn), tuple,
                          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
```

### Helper function

I can't see how you would avoid to use a helper function (besides using a `tuple_transform` function, which you're currently implementing).

You'll see I use a forwarding reference for the function argument, since it can be expensive to copy.

I keep the const lvalue reference for the tuple argument, because it's more simple (a forwarding reference wouldn't allow to constrain the type, and `sizeof...` wouldn't be possible either), but mainly because I can't see a case where the tuple would be consumed differently as a rvalue reference.

Comment: This is a good answer, but consider using `std::invoke` and `std::invoke_result_t` to handle (for instance) a member function pointer and a tuple of derived classes.

Comment: 1. I'd like to stick to C++14 if possible (which is how I tagged the question) - can't yet rely on C++17-capable compilers everywhere. 2. Your alternative solution is not really a review of my code. Also - why use recursive instantiation? I mean, what's the benefit? 3. If I called it tuple_map,, it might get confused with the map data structures in C++, don't you think?

Comment: @einpoklum: 1. C++14 is just a bit less readable, that's why I chose to use C++17, but there isn't any major difficulty to overcome. Just use `std::conditional` and tag dispatching. 2. I wasn't sure what your aim was, I intended to show you what a `transform` adaptation to tuple could be so that the alternative `map` vs `transform` would be clear. I don't see any recursive instantiation here? 3. well they are the same when you think of it (I mean, a function is a list of key / value pairs). The signature should help others to figure out which is which.

Answer (score 6):

### Code review

I agree with @papagaga that the name could be better, though I would choose `perform_mappping`. I just obfuscated name `map`, which is mostly thought of as `std::map`. I hope it will do more good than bad.

If the code doesn't have forwarding (or, as some call it, universal reference), don't use `std::forward`. In the case in question, there is none.

The code will generate a new function for each permutation of the types passed in. It might create a binary bloat if compiler will not be able to inline the function. Though, I believe in compilers. No conversions will ever happen, unless SFINAE kicks in.

With C++20's full templates on lambdas, the code might be able to hide the helper inside of itself, thus not exposing it.

---

### Alternative

`std::array` and `std::pair` are tuples too, from the point of view of standard library. I thought "hey, lets make the function to work uniformly on every tuple by standard library". I thought it's gonna be easy ... unless I realized that `std::array` has non-type argument in it. This turned things to be verbose and not as elegant as I thought. Yet, the caller side is still good.

### Implementation

The small problem is distinguishing tuples from non-tuples. `std::tuple_size` helps out with this. The harder one is identifying which type to return. Unfortunately I had to specialize it for tuple + pair and for array.

---

### Code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

namespace details
{
    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type;

    template <template <typename ...> typename Tuple, typename ... Types, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type<Tuple<Types...>, Mapping>
    {
        using type = Tuple<std::invoke_result_t<Mapping, Types>...>;
    };
    template <template <typename, std::size_t> typename Array, 
              typename T, std::size_t Size, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type<Array<T, Size>, Mapping>
    {
        using type = Array<std::invoke_result_t<Mapping, T>, Size>;
    };

    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping>
    using return_type_t = typename return_type<Tuple, Mapping>::type;

    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping, std::size_t ... Indices>
    return_type_t<std::decay_t<Tuple>, 
                  std::decay_t<Mapping>> perform_mapping(Tuple&& tup, 
                                                         Mapping&& mapping, 
                                                         std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    {
        return {mapping(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup)))...};
    }
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping, 
          std::size_t Size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>
auto perform_mapping(Tuple&& tup, Mapping&& mapping)
{
    return details::perform_mapping(std::forward<Tuple>(tup), 
                                    std::forward<Mapping>(mapping), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto mapper = [](int x) {return x * 2;};
    std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
    auto b = perform_mapping(a, mapper);

    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1, std::string{"a"});
    auto self_adder = [](const auto& x) {return x + x;};
    auto another_tuple = perform_mapping(tuple, self_adder);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(another_tuple) << ' ' << std::get<1>(another_tuple) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UIhglvD3U6tIUr5e).

---

In theory, if one specializes `std::tuple_size` for their own tuple (as long as it behaves like `std::tuple` or like `std::array`), it should simply work.

For better or for worse, the new function allows mutation and side effects.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost’s implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#tuple) has a few details I spot:

```
// tuple_for_each
namespace detail
{

template<class Tp, std::size_t... J, class F> BOOST_CONSTEXPR F tuple_for_each_impl( Tp && tp, integer_sequence<std::size_t, J...>, F && f )
{
    using A = int[sizeof...(J)];
    return (void)A{ ((void)f(std::get<J>(std::forward<Tp>(tp))), 0)... }, std::forward<F>(f);
}

template<class Tp, class F> BOOST_CONSTEXPR F tuple_for_each_impl( Tp && /*tp*/, integer_sequence<std::size_t>, F && f )
{
    return std::forward<F>(f);
}

} // namespace detail

template<class Tp, class F> BOOST_CONSTEXPR F tuple_for_each( Tp && tp, F && f )
{
    using seq = make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<Tp>::type>::value>;
    return detail::tuple_for_each_impl( std::forward<Tp>(tp), seq(), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

- it uses `remove_reference`
- it forwards the tuple by reference to the helper rather than copying it
- it uses constexpr

It doesn’t return the tuple of results though, but rather just returns the function object.  So you would `make_tuple` instead of `(void)`-int the results.

Incomputable: In your version, can you use return type deduction and avoid the horrendous meta-computation for the return type?  Let `make_tuple` do the argument deduction on the results and figure it out.

Comment: Isn't the remove_reference only used to choose the tuple size type? And isn't that type only `size_t` with `std::tuple`?

Comment: Yea, I guess it's to support compilers that didn’t have `sizeof...(Args)`  No... but the top function _does_ use it.  Maybe because it can handle tuple-like objects that have the `get<n>` protocol and doesn’t assume `size_t`?

Comment: No... `make_index_sequence` just takes the number, not a type.  It is sanitizing the metacall to `tuple_size`, maybe because it fails on references since that is the wrong type?  Try calling yours with a tuple *reference* variable as an argument.